# finding the volume of a cube, why doesn't my solution work

Tags: geometry, volume

****Question**:** the distance from a corner to the centre of a cube is 6. what is the volume of the cube?

**Answer:** 332.55

I drew a figure of a cube and two lines from a corner to their opposite corner and labeled the middle of the cube **e**. the triangle **aec** is right angled because the 2 lines make 4 equal angles when they intersect at **e**. knowing this and that the distance from a corner to **e** is 6, I calculated **ac** to be 8.49 or √72 using the Pythagorean theorem. Since I know **ac** is 8.49, I calculated **x** to be 6. 6³ is 216, so the volume of the cube is 216. Please tell me where I went wrong, Thank You.[image]

Comment: Hint: Review your justification that AEC is a right triangle.

Comment: You should be able to tell from your diagram that the four angles at the center of the cube are **not** equal. All four angles are apex angles of isosceles triangles whose equal sides are $6.$ But the triangles for two angles have base length equal to the side of the cube, whereas the base of the other two triangles is $\sqrt2$ times the side of the cube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angle $\angle AEC$ is NOT $90^{\circ}$, which is why your approach doesn't quite work.

Another approach -- the distance between two opposite corners is the diameter of the sphere, i.e. $12$. This implies the side of the cube is $12/\sqrt{3}$ (can you see why?), which gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 diagonal lines [through the center of the cube] make 4 angles but the lines are not on a plane.

Let $x$ be the length of an edge of the cube. Then the length of a diagonal *of* a side is $x\sqrt{2}$. Furthermore, there is a right triangle where the legs are 1. the diagonal of a side [such as say from the lower-right to upper-left corner of the side facing us in your picture], 2. an edge--such as the lower edge of the right side of the cube, and where the hypo is a diagonal across the entire cube.

This gives us $x^2 + 2x^2 = (6+6)^2$ which gives us $x =\sqrt{48}$; and $x^3=48\sqrt{48}$ is the answer.